# Is there any way to emulate a click event WITHOUT focusing the window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus, mouseevent

I am trying to write a function that, in Google Chrome, will open tabs in the background (without losing focus to the current window), but also, can keep doing this, looping through an array of URLs, WITHOUT focusing the main browser window if it is minimized or otherwise unfocused.

This is part of a Chrome extension I am writing so I only care about compatibility with Google Chrome.

To ensure that tabs open in the background, I am using the following functions, which I did not write but have found to work very well. As I understand this is simply simulating a Ctrl+Click.

```
function emulateClick(element){
    var evt = element.ownerDocument.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, element.ownerDocument.defaultView, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, true, false, false, true, 0, null);

    if (document.createEventObject){
        element.fireEvent('onclick', evt)
    } else{
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}

function openTabs(x) {
$.each(x, function (index, url) {
    var $link = $('<a>', {
        "target" : "_blank",
        "href" : url
    });
emulateClick($link.get(0));
    });
}
```

The problem however is that every time the emulated click event is fired, even if the browser window is minimised, it will pop back up into the foreground, interrupting whatever else I am doing. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

Comment: This seems very much like it could be used for nefarious purposes.  Most browsers don't allow this type of behavior specifically to prevent endless popup ads, like the kind prevalent in the late '90s and early 2000s.

Comment: So it's likely not possible? Thinking about it, I guess obviously it's not the emulated click which gives the window focus, but the action of opening a new tab, as `.click()` scripts don't do this if the clicked element is just a button or something.

Comment: Yeah, I would say that it's not possible.

Comment: Ah well. I think I have come up with an alternative option. Instead of opening multiple tabs, I will just dynamically insert multiple iframes to perform the same function. Thanks anyway for your input.